# How can I check if the mouse cursor is past a certain x coordinate?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What am I doing wrong? When I attempt to use this it spits the error:

> Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined.

The goal here is to run a check to see if the mouse cursor is passed a certain x position.

```js
$( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
  $( "#log" ).text( "pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY );
});

var x = event.pageX; 
if (x > 1200)
{
  window.alert("Working");
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eef;
}
div {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: You're closing your `mousemove` listener too early, close it after the `if` statement. Since you are new, it is important to learn about the DevTools of the browser (press F12) this will help a lot to identify errors

Comment: ```var x = event.pageX; if (x > 1200) { window.alert("Working"); }``` should be inside the callback function of mousemove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to evaluate the event outside the function where is defined. Move that code inside of the function and it will work.

```js
$( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
$( "#log" ).text( "pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY );

 var x = event.pageX; 
 if (x > 1200) {
  window.alert("Working");
 }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #eef;
}
div {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The console error explains the issue quite clearly - `event` is undefined. The only place in your code where an `event` variable is in scope is in your callback for the `mousemove` event (where it is the function parameter). So you just need to move the relevant code inside the callback function - like this:

```
$( document ).on( "mousemove", function( event ) {
  $( "#log" ).text( "pageX: " + event.pageX + ", pageY: " + event.pageY );
  var x = event.pageX; 
  if (x > 1200)
  {
    window.alert("Working");
  } 
});
```